# rolling in data table

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I am trying to map two data sets with uid and timestamp.
One is add to cart data and other is final transaction data, I am able to join these two based on rolling argument with data.table . However owing to the nature of my data set i am missing out on some matches. It would be  great if any direction can be provided.

Here is my attempt:
I am giving the sample data for a user id so i can let you know about where i am missing out 
This is the add_to cart_data :

```
structure(list(uid = c("1000017637676410451", "1000017637676410451", 
"1000017637676410451"), dt = structure(c(1490150844, 1490151029, 
1490151435), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    price = c(14.99, 4.06, 2.12), name = c("NEW MUSYSIC LAVALIER MICROPHONE WITH CLIP AND WINDSCREEN FOR WIRELESS MIC SYSTEM", 
    "LAVALIER TIE CLIP LAPEL MICROPHONE MIC FOR SENNHEISER 3.5mm SCREW LOCK PLUG", 
    "NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC"
    )), .Names = c("uid", "dt", "price", "name"), sorted = c("uid", 
"dt"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006530788>)
```

Here is the final transaction data :

```
structure(list(dt = structure(c(1490151670, 1490151671, 1490151671
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), uid = c("1000017637676410451", 
"1000017637676410451", "1000017637676410451")), .Names = c("dt", 
"uid"), sorted = c("uid", "dt"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006530788>)
```

This is what i tried with `roll=+Inf` of data.table option where i tried mapping nearest cart addition to final transaction making sure cart addition time stamp is prior to transaction completion time stamp.

```
    setkey(final_sub,uid,dt)
    setkey(cart_sub,uid,dt)

    test_infpos <- cart_sub[final_sub,roll=+Inf]
    test_infpos_sub
```

This is the output i get :

```
                  uid                  dt price                                                                           name
1: 1000017637676410451 2017-03-22 03:01:10  2.12 NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC
2: 1000017637676410451 2017-03-22 03:01:11  2.12 NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC
3: 1000017637676410451 2017-03-22 03:01:11  2.12 NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC
```

So what is happening is last cart addition is attributed to all conversions which is actually correct looking at  what `roll=+Inf` does, but as you can see all add to cart transactions are very close when it comes to timestamp of each of them and final transaction also have very close time stamps , would it be possible if such join can include or club all them in to one, basically all 3 cart values can be assigned to all the 3 final transaction.
This is just one sample of data , so ideally if there is a way to use `roll` argument to nearest uid,dt combination  and also take into consideration if there are time stamps very close to each other the roll window can be applied to all of them on top of just the `nearest roll`.

This is how i want the output for such cases to look like:

```
                  uid                  dt price                                                                           name
1: 1000017637676410451 2017-03-22 03:01:10  2.12 NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC, LAVALIER TIE CLIP LAPEL MICROPHONE MIC FOR SENNHEISER 3.5mm SCREW LOCK PLUG,NEW MUSYSIC LAVALIER MICROPHONE WITH CLIP AND WINDSCREEN FOR WIRELESS MIC SYSTEM
2: 1000017637676410451 2017-03-22 03:01:11  2.12 NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC, LAVALIER TIE CLIP LAPEL MICROPHONE MIC FOR SENNHEISER 3.5mm SCREW LOCK PLUG,NEW MUSYSIC LAVALIER MICROPHONE WITH CLIP AND WINDSCREEN FOR WIRELESS MIC SYSTEM
3: 1000017637676410451 2017-03-22 03:01:11  2.12 NEW Pro Lavalier Lapel Microphone For Wireless Microphone system Mono 3.5mm PC, LAVALIER TIE CLIP LAPEL MICROPHONE MIC FOR SENNHEISER 3.5mm SCREW LOCK PLUG,NEW MUSYSIC LAVALIER MICROPHONE WITH CLIP AND WINDSCREEN FOR WIRELESS MIC SYSTEM
```

Any direction on this would be very helpful

Comment: To me it seems you get what you want. But most likely, I've overseen something. Perhaps you should try to through out everything, which is not relevant for your problem.

Comment: Hey as I updated my final output, would it be possible to get something done on those lines, what I am getting I have posted, also I have posted my desired output.  So ` roll = +Inf`  would give me next closest uid and timestamp that happened in add_to_cart , i want to club all add_to_cart if they have very close uid,timestamps combination (we can decide the closeness lets say 1 min difference) and attribute all these add_to_cart to final transaction while joining.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Are looking for grouping? Something like `group_by` from `dplyr`? See [here](http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/dplyr_tutorial.html)

Comment: @Christoph what `group_by` from dplyr has to do with anything really?

Comment: hey Guys, I was able to somehow circumvent my problem by defining sessions based on timestamps and clubbing all timestamps that can be considered as one session by a user_id in add_to_cart data, and then joining with `roll=nearest `would yield me my desired result matching final transaction with nearest session  in add_to_cart data(rather than joining to individual timestamps, i attributed each timestamps of a session to the lowest timestamp of that session of att_to_cart data). Let me know if you have any better ideas.